gazebo wrong tf alignment
ROS Noetic, ubuntu 20.04
So I was trying simulate a robot in gazebo environment with ROS. The base I used is bunker. I basically added in a VLP-16 and kinect camera similar to how they did it in turtlebot3. Here's my /ugv_gazebo_sim/bunker/bunker_gazebo_sim/urdf/bunker.xacro that I modified:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-1-g15f4949  Build Version: 1.6.7594.29634
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot  name="bunker_description" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:property name="r200_cam_rgb_px" value="0.005"/>
  <xacro:property name="r200_cam_rgb_py" value="0.018"/>
  <xacro:property name="r200_cam_rgb_pz" value="0.013"/>
  <xacro:property name="r200_cam_depth_offset" value="0.01"/>

  <xacro:include filename="$(find velodyne_description)/urdf/VLP-16.urdf.xacro"/>
  <xacro:VLP-16>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.4" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </xacro:VLP-16>

  <link name="base_link">
     <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0212410555532523 0.00475458359568469 -0.127580557949736"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.607716166684979"
        ixy="1.92178193996147E-05"
        ixz="-0.036532069356182"
        iyy="1.70041426855404"
        iyz="2.16963122007266E-05"
        izz="1.84232351935185" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0.53 -0.392 -0.358"
        rpy="1.57 0 3.14" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/BUNKER.STL" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5  1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0.53 -0.392 -0.358"
        rpy="1.57 0 3.14" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/BUNKER.STL" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link
    name="wheel1_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 -1.38777878078145E-17 -0.0719999999999999"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000378440530116381"
        ixy="5.60822736805661E-21"
        ixz="3.04207802822425E-20"
        iyy="0.000378440530116381"
        iyz="-7.56626980356474E-21"
        izz="0.000710150518820894" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel1_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.44403 0.3495 -0.12853"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel1_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel1.1_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.74279013442913E-08 5.87093572021469E-08 -0.0720000000000001"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="6.58750963981394E-05"
        ixy="-1.46558944641469E-09"
        ixz="-8.34967331718859E-12"
        iyy="6.58795984671517E-05"
        iyz="-2.4786046130206E-12"
        izz="0.000112721820875598" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel1.1_jont"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.37551 0.3495 -0.22305"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel1.1_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel1.2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="1.66533453693773E-16 4.16333634234434E-17 -0.0720000000000002"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000179574259018481"
        ixy="1.15789498120549E-20"
        ixz="1.3563351843978E-21"
        iyy="0.000179574259018481"
        iyz="6.0369822309622E-23"
        izz="0.000332594534732139" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel1.2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.29039 0.3495 -0.28104"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel1.2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel1.3_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="3.44025652177504E-05 -2.66346274915008E-05 -0.0701504149473696"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000105254202004996"
        ixy="1.32328029886322E-08"
        ixz="3.84294589102693E-11"
        iyy="0.000105248656147198"
        iyz="-1.41155611914915E-11"
        izz="0.000173280771745758" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel1.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel1.3_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.29603 0.3495 -0.087"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel1.3_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.66533453693773E-16 0 0.072"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000378440530116381"
        ixy="3.37302217863781E-21"
        ixz="2.71827270955143E-20"
        iyy="0.000378440530116381"
        iyz="-7.32821644893157E-21"
        izz="0.000710150518820894" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.44403 -0.3495 -0.12853"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel2.1_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.74279017328693E-08 5.87093572160247E-08 0.0720000000000002"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="6.58750963981394E-05"
        ixy="-1.46558944642761E-09"
        ixz="-8.34967332343028E-12"
        iyy="6.58795984671517E-05"
        iyz="-2.47860459929511E-12"
        izz="0.000112721820875598" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel2.1_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.37551 -0.3495 -0.22305"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel2.1_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel2.2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.38777878078145E-16 -4.85722573273506E-17 0.0720000000000003"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00017957425901848"
        ixy="6.28960386226657E-21"
        ixz="2.14010788664762E-21"
        iyy="0.00017957425901848"
        iyz="1.27709655724716E-22"
        izz="0.000332594534732139" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel2.2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.29039 -0.3495 -0.28104"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel2.2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel2.3_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="3.51083051564616E-05 -2.7181014665284E-05 0.0709276770204769"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000105035118852508"
        ixy="1.32328029886296E-08"
        ixz="3.84294589110161E-11"
        iyy="0.00010502957299471"
        iyz="-1.41155611875745E-11"
        izz="0.00017298179736849" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel2.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel2.3_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.29603 -0.3495 -0.087"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel2.3_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel3_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.5143569731535E-10 7.07767178198537E-16 -0.0246054820762604"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00232456013775523"
        ixy="-1.61343020248111E-09"
        ixz="-4.5670735364335E-13"
        iyy="0.00232456564213727"
        iyz="-1.36036258272812E-18"
        izz="0.00308347787030649" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel3_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.38871 0.295 -0.19381"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel3_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel3.1_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="5.55111512312578E-17 5.55111512312578E-17 -0.0720000000000002"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000179574259018481"
        ixy="-1.73824343982442E-20"
        ixz="-2.53159654382751E-21"
        iyy="0.000179574259018481"
        iyz="-3.13741449878515E-21"
        izz="0.000332594534732139" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel3.1_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.23111 0.3495 -0.27671"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel3.1_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel3.2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="7.58128369110489E-17 7.63278329429795E-17 -0.0720000000000003"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00017957425901848"
        ixy="9.82929052458426E-22"
        ixz="1.10990388135291E-21"
        iyy="0.00017957425901848"
        iyz="-4.81322327079121E-21"
        izz="0.000332594534732139" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel3.2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.043885 0.3495 -0.27671"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel3.2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel3.3_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="1.37732703020532E-08 -5.29206664124648E-05 -0.0701501700151683"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000105264944409738"
        ixy="7.98231761628902E-12"
        ixz="6.80400273605472E-11"
        iyy="0.000105238344260685"
        iyz="-2.72106317781962E-11"
        izz="0.000173281039335396" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel3.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel3.3_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.28597 0.3495 -0.087"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel3.3_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel4_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="5.55111512312578E-17 1.51436273243544E-10 0.0245928853369881"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00232456564213727"
        ixy="-1.6134302023684E-09"
        ixz="-3.67391703208082E-19"
        iyy="0.00232456013775523"
        iyz="-4.56707494796216E-13"
        izz="0.00308347787030649" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel4_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.38871 -0.295 -0.19381"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel4_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel4.1_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-1.11022302462516E-16 -5.55111512312578E-17 0.0720000000000002"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000179574259018481"
        ixy="-7.93399024302093E-21"
        ixz="-2.13342044570487E-21"
        iyy="0.000179574259018481"
        iyz="-3.23624373974149E-21"
        izz="0.000332594534732139" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4.1_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel4.1_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.23111 -0.3495 -0.27671"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel4.1_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel4.2_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-7.64498056873841E-17 -4.85722573273506E-17 0.0720000000000004"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.00017957425901848"
        ixy="6.3005828905746E-22"
        ixz="1.1753358195074E-22"
        iyy="0.00017957425901848"
        iyz="-3.27347099653111E-21"
        izz="0.000332594534732139" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4.2_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel4.2_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0.043885 -0.3495 -0.27671"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel4.2_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 -1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="wheel4.3_Link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="1.37732700244975E-08 -5.29206664124926E-05 0.0701152686893121"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0001" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.000105264944409738"
        ixy="7.98231761858719E-12"
        ixz="6.80400273764357E-11"
        iyy="0.000105238344260685"
        iyz="-2.72106317797361E-11"
        izz="0.000173281039335396" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="1 1 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://bunker_description/meshes/wheel4.3_Link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="wheel4.3_joint"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.28597 -0.3495 -0.087"
      rpy="1.5708 0 -3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="wheel4.3_Link" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
    <limit
      lower="-180"
      upper="180"
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />
  </joint>

  <joint name="camera_0_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.064 -0.065 0.194" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="camera_0_link"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_0_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57 0 1.57"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://turtlebot3_description/meshes/sensors/r200.dae" />
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.003 0.065 0.007" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.012 0.132 0.020"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="camera_0_rgb_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0.005 0.018 0.013" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="camera_0_link"/>
    <child link="camera_0_rgb_frame"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="camera_0_rgb_frame"/>

  <joint name="camera_0_rgb_optical_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="-1.57 0 -1.57"/>
    <parent link="camera_0_rgb_frame"/>
    <child link="camera_0_rgb_optical_frame"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="camera_0_rgb_optical_frame"/>
  <joint name="camera_0_depth_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="${r200_cam_rgb_px} ${r200_cam_rgb_py + r200_cam_depth_offset} ${r200_cam_rgb_pz}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="camera_0_link"/>
    <child link="camera_0_depth_frame"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="camera_0_depth_frame"/>

  <joint name="camera_0_depth_optical_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="-1.57 0 -1.57"/>
    <parent link="camera_0_depth_frame"/>
    <child link="camera_0_depth_optical_frame"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="camera_0_depth_optical_frame"/>

  <!-- /////////////////////////////////   gazebo color   ////////////////////////////////////// -->

 <gazebo reference="base_link">
     <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="camera_0_rgb_frame">
    <sensor type="depth" name="realsense_R200">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>false
      </visualize>
      <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.3439</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
              <width>1920</width>
              <height>1080</height>
              <format>R8G8B8</format>
          </image>
          <depth_camera></depth_camera>
          <clip>
              <near>0.03</near>
              <far>100</far>
          </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
        <baseline>0.2</baseline>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
        <cameraName>camera_0</cameraName>
        <frameName>camera_0_rgb_optical_frame</frameName>
        <imageTopicName>rgb/image_raw</imageTopicName>
        <depthImageTopicName>depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
        <pointCloudTopicName>depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
        <cameraInfoTopicName>rgb/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
        <depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>depth/camera_info</depthImageCameraInfoTopicName>
        <pointCloudCutoff>0.4</pointCloudCutoff>
            <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
            <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
            <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
            <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
            <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
            <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        <CxPrime>0.0</CxPrime>
        <Cx>0.0</Cx>
        <Cy>0.0</Cy>
        <focalLength>0</focalLength>
        <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- <gazebo>
    <plugin name="object_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_planar_move.so">
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <odometryRate>20.0</odometryRate>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo> -->
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="object_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_planar_move.so">
      <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
      <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
      <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
      <odometryRate>20.0</odometryRate>
      <leftFrontJoint>wheel1_2_joint</leftFrontJoint>
      <rightFrontJoint>wheel2_2_joint</rightFrontJoint>
      <leftRearJoint>wheel3_1_joint</leftRearJoint>
      <rightRearJoint>wheel4_1_joint</rightRearJoint>
      <robotBaseFrame>base_link</robotBaseFrame>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  
  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <!-- <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace> -->
      <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
      <legacyModeNS>true</legacyModeNS>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

</robot>


Now it generated the tf tree:

However, when I went to view it in rviz, the tf alignment was wrong:

I looked into it more and it seems that the robot is tilted sideway a little bit:

I'm not sure if that affects it or not, but I'm not sure how I can fix it. I'd appreciated any feedback! Thank you!
Update: I used gazebo tool to turn it so that it's not sideway, but problem is still there:


Looking at your urdf, the problem may be that you have not used enough precision when specifying your 90 degree rotations: my advice is to use at least 6 decimal digits.
Another possibility is the surface of the tires are irregular, causing the robot body to lean.

I did the same for turtlebot3 waffle and same problem.

adding decimal didn't fix it
